# Need Help Building ASP.NET Core Source Because of Missing .Net Version

Tags: asp.net-core

I can't seem to find the version of asp.net core that is wanted to build what is at the current asp.net core site. I'm currently getting the error that vs is looking for v 1.0.0-preview2-1-003180 but I can't find that anywhere to install. I'ved looked here:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

What is the recommended way to download the source from

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

and build it. (I'm on the dev branch).

[image]

Update:
There are 13 projects in the solution.  There is a global.json in solution and a project.json in each project.

Here is the global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test/WebSites",
    "samples"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003180"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET Core does your `project.json` file specify? The `frameworks` property would specify which version of .NET will be used.

Comment: I updated question with global.json.  I assume that is what you were looking for.

Comment: `global.json` definitely helps, but the [project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json) has some key compilation information as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating `"frameworks"` property of `project.json` to something like:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.1.0"
      }
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
},
```

This should target .NET Core 1.1 rather than the specific SDK version you are receiving an error on.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That did help but now I still get 311 errors when I build. It feels like I've forced a version that the source was not built for. Seems to me like the correct .net version is important.  For example, I get errors like:         Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS4027 'TaskAwaiter' does not implement 'INotifyCompletion' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 C:\VCProject\aspnet-Mvc\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test\CacheTagHelperTest.cs 416 Active

Comment: What does the `"dependencies"` property of the `project.json` look like? Are the various key dependencies set to something like "1.1.0"? Try maybe updating those versions then having it update the respective files. If that's a possibility for your project.

Comment: Yes you can't do that. ASP.NET Core is currently using a pre-release version of the toolchain and that version is specified in global.json for that specific reason.

Comment: @davidfowl I just want to compile a fairly recent version .net core so I can validate assumptions while debugging through source. Should I grab a different branch or checkin that will work with my latest vs2015?

Comment: Our build bootstraps the entire process, the trick is that you need to set add `%localappdata%\Microsoft\dotnet` to the path then launch VS

Comment: thanks @davidfowl but I'm still lost someplace.  I still get the error that I don't have the right .net version installed.  see error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4vr8v75uj2fyv0n/netcore003180error.png?dl=0

Comment: Run build.cmd, set the PATH variable on the command line via set PATH="localappdata%\Microsoft\dotnet;%PATH%",  open the .sln file from the command line.

Comment: thanks @davidfowl  I ran build.cmd with path, ran for about 15 minutes until erroring. log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/d86jna4hciku4b9/buildcmd_log.txt?dl=0  VS2015 still fails with can't find 1.0.0-preview2-1-003180  Any Blog post on setting up vs2015 to build core from fresh install? (hate to keep bugging you)